# EJB Packaging structure

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb, war, ear

I have a simple J2EE application made up of a web-tier (WAR), an EJB tier(interfaces/implementations) and a business tier (JAR).

The 3 tiers are defined as separate projects, and I am trying to package them as an EAR. I created an EAR in NetBeans with existing sources, and the project will build. The issue is I'm having trouble understanding the dependency structure, and where the jars should be located with respect to the EAR that is producted. For the project to run:

```
-The WAR has a dependency on the business tier project and the EJB project
-The EJB project has a dependency on the business tier project.
```

When I look at the EAR I see:

```
lib
  ..dependencies that the war needs (some apache jars, etc)
  ..appEJB.jar
  ..appbusinesslogic.jar
meta-inf
appEJB.jar
appWAR.war
```

So it looks like my dependency structure is incorrect since I'm seeing duplication. I would expect to see the apache jars packaged with the WAR, and the lib directory for the EAR would be empty.

Can anyone help me understand what I may need to fix?